Exact computation with fractional powers as integer bounds
Context: I am implementing the prime-counting function $\pi(x)$ with the Meissel-Lehmer algorithm, extended by Lagarias, Miller, and Odlyzko. The notation comes from an overview by Oliveira e Silva. $\pi(x)$ counts the number of primes $\le x$, and $x$ could be a real number, in which case it would equal $π(\lfloor x \rfloor)$.
Exact quantities like $a = \pi(\alpha\sqrt[3]x)$ and $m > \alpha \sqrt[3]{x} / p$  are needed for exact bounds, where $x, \alpha, p$ are integer. The issue with something simple like alpha * x**(1/3) / p in python is that it uses floating point calculations and sometimes it is off by a tiny amount, enough to change a precise bound. For example, an upper bound computed by 125**(1/3) == 4.999999999999999, and soint(125**(1/3)) < 5. It doesn't make sense to always round up or down due to this error which may be a little under or a little over an exact integer.
How can I guarantee my bounds are always exact? Because the input variables are only integers, I thought of doing something like rounding to the nearest integer if it's within a small epsilon, say 1e-12. For example, (10**12)**(1/3) == 9999.999999999995 and would get rounded to 1000, but (10**12+1)**(1/3) == 10000.000000003329 is too far from the actual answer to be FP error.
The more appealing idea is to use integer arithmetic as much as possible. Fastest square root method with exact integer result? also suggests assuming the error is < 1 and just checking the adjacent values of our guess output. For example, for cuberoot, check the guesses by cubing the result and checking the bounds exactly with integers. Or for cuberoot, use an integer Newton's method that is guaranteed correct.
I'm sure this problem has been discussed before. I think what I proposed should work but I'm not fully convinced of the correctness. I assume both methods are very fast too because only one floating point operation is needed?

I don't fully understand what you're asking. The whole prime counting introduction is a red herring: the only correct answer is computing the integer square / cuberoot exactly, so we can reduce the problem to that. And you've already found an answer to that problem, so what is still unclear?

I'd like to verify my logic. and also about the fudge factor: I think it needs to be smaller than any cbrt(x+1) - cbrt(x) but bigger than FP error. I'm not sure if that's rigorous

I think the floating point implementation is just not worth the time thinking about. It's less efficient and just not the correct approach unless it just 'happens' to work out with some smudge, for a small limited input domain.

If all numbers are positive, $m > \alpha \sqrt[3]{x} / p$ is the same as $(pm)^3 >\alpha^3 x$. You might need larger integers though. You could also consider an iterative method (e.g. Newton-Raphson) to compute $\alpha \sqrt[3]{x}$ as an integer.

@Pseudonym yes I ended up doing the adjacent checks since these cases I have integer checks. Pypy has large integers but if I wrote it in a real language I think the bounds still work out to fit in a 64 bit int.
